# Making superscript, numbered citations in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, citations

Is there a way to have citations in Word 2013 appear as superscript numbers? I cannot find an included style that renders the citation in this way.

I know that the EndNote plugin can do this but I don't have endnote. I am also aware that the XML files can be edited, but I have no idea where to start there, nor do I have the time to learn it in detail.

(Additionally, the style should render sequential citations using a range, so "1,2,3", should render as "1-3".)

Is there a straightforward way of doing this?